# Why does my pushViewController not work

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

When I hit an element in my tableView it comes up with an error. I have checked all of the connections but still cant work it out. Here is my code

```
#import "CGViewController.h"

#import "CGAppDelegate.h"

#import "sls.h"

#import "patientController.h"

@interface CGViewController ()

@end

@implementation CGViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Patients";
    CGAppDelegate *delegate =
    (CGAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    patients = delegate.patients;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if( nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row < patients.count) {
        sls *thissls = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = thissls.patientName;
    }
        else {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"";
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        return cell;
}


-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ( editing != self.editing) {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

        NSArray *indexes =
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:
         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:patients.count inSection:0]];
        if ( editing == YES ) {
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
          }  else {
              [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row < patients.count ) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:
(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger count = patients.count;
    if (self.editing) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return count;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGAppDelegate *delegate =
    (CGAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    patientController *patient = [[patientController alloc] init];
    [delegate.navController pushViewController:patient animated: YES];

    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated: YES];
}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editing forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editing == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [patients removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
@end
```

Any ideas on what is wrong if you know please can you help as soon as possible as i am on a deadline

Thanks in advance.

The error says `Thread 1:signal SIGABRT`

The error is in main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CGAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CGAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

it says that the error is here

`patientController *patient = [[patientController alloc] init];`

here is my patientController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface patientController : UIViewController {
    NSIndexPath *index;

    IBOutlet UIImageView * pictureView;
    IBOutlet UILabel * descriptionView1;
    IBOutlet UILabel * descriptionView2;
    IBOutlet UILabel * descriptionView3;
}

- (id)initwithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

and my .m file

```
#import "patientController.h"

#import "CGAppDelegate.h"

#import "sls.h"

@interface patientController ()

@end

@implementation patientController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    CGAppDelegate *delegate =
    (CGAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sls *thissls = [delegate.patients objectAtIndex:index.row];
    self.title = thissls.patientName;
    self->descriptionView1.text = thissls.patientName;
    self->descriptionView2.text = thissls.surnameName;
    self->descriptionView3.text = thissls.dateOfBirth;
    self->pictureView.image = thissls.patientImage;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (id)initwithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( (self == [super init]) ) {
        index = indexPath;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Please can anyone at all help

Comment: Is your view controller on top of the navigation's stack?

Comment: i dont really get what you are saying so can you put it into context in a block of code please?

Comment: Alright, 2 things :
- Add a new `exception breakpoint` in the breakpoint menu (left panel)
- Click on your project name (up left), `edit scheme`,`diagnostics` then `enable zombie objects`
It should allow you to catch the raised exception and display the real error

Comment: Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17121784/737105

Comment: where is the edit scheme. I'm useless

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/D1renXW.png

Comment: I put the breakpoint on the line of error

Comment: went to my breakpoints and right clicked on it but that option was not there

Comment: its not on the breakpoint, its next to the "stop" button, with the name of your project on it. And your breakpoint needs to be an exception breakpoint, I can't stress it enough.

Comment: i did what you said and it didn't tell me any different other than: `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1`

Comment: what do you mean by an exeption breakpoint

Comment: Wild guess: Are you working with threads and this is some sort of threading issue? I notice that the crash happens in thread 1, but the main thread is thread 0, if I remember correctly. I'm not near a computer, so I can't check myself, so just ignore me if I'm totally wrong.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tOMLGr8.png then http://i.imgur.com/NM1NE2h.png

Comment: This is iOS 101 by the way, every project you work on should have those options activated in order for you to debug your code.

Comment: i've put the error on the description

Comment: That's better, but you should now also see what exactly caused this line to raise an error in the console. I guess you have an issue in your `patientController` init code or something.

Comment: put the patientController.h file in question. Do the want the .m file as well?

Comment: Probably but I have to go so I won't be able to respond. Quick guess though, you declared IBOutlets without the `@property (strong, nonatomic)` before them. Also make sure that you correctly linked them in your .xib file. Cheers.

Comment: Also, have a look at my [sample project](http://alexiscreuzot.com/ColourLove) if you want to have something clean to figure out iOS dev.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `initwithIndexPath:` when you create `patientController`? Currently you are using `init` only, which means that the instance variable `index` in `patientController` is not initialized.

Comment: could you possibly give me a chunk of code

Comment: What I meant is, instead of `patientController *patient = [[patientController alloc] init];` you could say `patientController *patient = [[patientController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];`. A warning, though: I don't know if this is the right thing to do, **you** have written the original code, so it is you must decide.

Comment: Also two notes on how this site works: 1) If you want me to notice your comment, you must write my name in your comment like so: `@herzbube`. Next time you write a comment, click the "help" link that appears next to the text input field and it will tell you more. 2) I don't want to be rude, but in my opinion you should show a little bit more effort in solving your problem. Don't expect us to lead you by the hand step by step, it is your code, so you should be the one who understands it best. Also try to know your tools, e.g. you could google "exception breakpoint xcode" to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:patient animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 [self.navController pushViewController:patient animated: YES];
```

Every viewcontroller has its navigation controller reference in itself,no need to call the application delegate to invoke it[The navigation controller **Must** be initialised and all the viewcontrollers must be pushed into the navigation stack until this one to make it work]

So use this to setup the navigation controller in the appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

//Note : this is an example set like this with your viewcontroller instance
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: its on the description. just put it on

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently in a navigationController (which you have to in order to push a new ViewController), then you can push your new controller by just calling these lines

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   patientController *patient = [[patientController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:patient animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Also I advise you to deselect the selected row only in the `viewDidAppear` so the user can have a glance of what row he had selected when returning from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

To check where your exception is raised, in Xcode, in the breakpoints navigation tab click on the plus button in the bottom-left corner and add an `Exceptions Breakpoint`. Then run the app from Xcode. The next time an exception is raised, as in your case, the execution of your app will stop and Xcode will point at the line of code where the exception is raised.

Anyway, to make you understand how navigationControllers work:

UINavigationController is a UIViewController that controls a stack of other UIViewController instances. This other view controllers are said to be in the 'navigation stack'. The top item in the navigation stack is the view controller whose view you see at a given time onto the screen. You can push (present) or pop (dismiss) a view controller on/from the navigation stack.

A UINavigationController is initialized with a 'rootViewController' which is going to be it's first view controller onto the stack and therefore the first you see when you add the navigationController onto the screen (e.g. by setting it as the appDelegate window's rootViewController). Each UIViewController on the navigation stack references it's navigationController through the property 'navigationController'.

At any given point, you can use the UINavigationController methods `pushViewController:animated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:` or `popToViewController:animated:` or `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to add or remove viewControllers from the navigationStack. To see the results of this methods, of course, you should have the navigationController on screen.

For more informations refer to the [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I've asked you whether your viewController is on the navigationStack and you didn't know what it meant, therefore I'm giving you an explanation about navigation controllers. Anyway, I've edited my answer to also give you a tip on how to fix your issue as I saw you added more details about what problem you're getting in your question.